# Unable to run MR on cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have an Map reduce program that is running successfully in standalone(Ecllipse) mode but while trying to run the same MR by exporting the jar in cluster. It is showing null pointer exception like this,

```
  13/06/26 05:46:22 ERROR mypackage.HHDriver: Error while configuring run method. 
  java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I used the following code for run method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    Tool headOfHouseHold = new HHDriver();

    try {
        ToolRunner.run(configuration,headOfHouseHold,args);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error("Error while configuring run method", exception);
        // System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

run method:

```
if (args != null && args.length == 8) {
    // Setting the Configurations
    GenericOptionsParser genericOptionsParser=new GenericOptionsParser(args);
    Configuration configuration=genericOptionsParser.getConfiguration();

    //Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    configuration.set("fs.default.name", args[0]);
    configuration.set("mapred.job.tracker", args[1]);
    configuration.set("deltaFlag",args[2]);                                   
    configuration.set("keyPrefix",args[3]);
    configuration.set("outfileName",args[4]);
    configuration.set("Inpath",args[5]);
    String outputPath=args[6];

    configuration.set("mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution", "false");
    configuration.set("mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution", "false");

    // To avoid the creation of _LOG and _SUCCESS files
    configuration.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false");
    configuration.set("hadoop.job.history.user.location", "none");
    configuration.set(Constants.MAX_NUM_REDUCERS,args[7]);

    // Configuration of the MR-Job
    Job job = new Job(configuration, "HH Job");
    job.setJarByClass(HHDriver.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setNumReduceTasks(HouseHoldingHelper.numReducer(configuration));
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job,configuration.get("outfileName"),
                                   TextOutputFormat.class,Text.class,Text.class);

    // Deletion of OutputTemp folder (if exists)
    FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(configuration);
    Path path = new Path(outputPath);

    if (path != null /*&& path.depth() >= 5*/) {
        fileSystem.delete(path, true);
    }

    // Deletion of empty files in the output (if exists)
    FileStatus[] fileStatus = fileSystem.listStatus(new Path(outputPath));
    for (FileStatus file : fileStatus) {
        if (file.getLen() == 0) {
            fileSystem.delete(file.getPath(), true);
        }
     }
    // Setting the Input/Output paths
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(configuration.get("Inpath")));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));

    job.setMapperClass(HHMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(HHReducer.class);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
```

I double checked the run method parameters those are not null and it is running in standalone mode as well..

Comment: are you creating the hadoop configuration properly? More importantly is your MR job dependent on external jars?

Comment: @JitB Yes. I checked it

Answer (score 1):

Issue could be because the hadoop configuration is not properly getting passed to your program.
You can try putting this in the beginning of your driver class:

```
GenericOptionsParser genericOptionsParser=new GenericOptionsParser(args[]);
Configuration hadoopConfiguration=genericOptionsParser.getConfiguration();
```

Then use the `hadoopConfiguration` object when initializing objects.

e.g.

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {        
    GenericOptionsParser genericOptionsParser=new GenericOptionsParser(args[]);
    Configuration hadoopConfiguration=genericOptionsParser.getConfiguration();

    Job job = new Job(hadoopConfiguration);
    //set other stuff
}
```

Comment: You are asking to place these lines instead of using run method??

Comment: No, these go in the run method, use this to create the Configuration object, before you create your hadoop fs object.

Comment: I think the problem could be in  ToolRunner.run(configuration,headOfHouseHold,args);
Since you are actually using the command line arguments in your run method they need to be cleaned before you use them.
So instead of passing args, you need to pass genericOptionsParser.getRemainingArgs() so that hadoop specific arguments are cleaned off

So you need to integrate the above code segment for hadoopConfiguration object in your main method since you need to use the cl arguments in your job configuration.

Comment: Can you sysout your arguments in run() method? Some value that is expected by your code is not being set properly while running from command line.